# adding MathContextin stream

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have this piece of code that sets a BigDecimal:

```
setTotalDogsCurrentValueInUsd(
            purchases
                .stream()
                .map(p -> p.getNumberOfDogs())
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add).multiply(new BigDecimal(rate)));
```

I would like to add `MathContext.DECIMAL32` to round but I don't know where to add it exaclty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#multiply-java.math.BigDecimal-java.math.MathContext-) overload of multiply:

```
.multiply(new BigDecimal(rate), MathContext.DECIMAL32)
```

or if you want to apply it during the `reduce` call:

```
.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (a, b) -> a.add(b,  MathContext.DECIMAL32))
```